# How to return items from for loop as a single variable?

Tags: python, variables, loops, for-loop

I'm new to python and I don't really understand for loops. 
Given a string, I want to abbreviate the first letter in each word.

This is my code:

```
def abbreviate (phrase):
     x=phrase.split()

for i in range(0,len(x)):
    print x[len(x)-len(x)+i][0].lower()
```

It prints:

```
t
b
o
n
t
b
```

How would I get this output into a variable `abv= 'tbnotb'`?

Answer (score 3):

```
def abbreviate(phrase):
     return ''.join([word[0] for word in phrase.lower().split()])

>>> abv = abbreviate('Red Hot Chili Peppers')
>>> abv
'rhcp'
```

You may want to read about [list comprehensions](http://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/datastructures.html#list-comprehensions) and [str.join()](http://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#str.join) method.

Answer (score 0):

```
print ''.join([w[0] for w in x.split()])
```